# iPhone SDK - Highlight the selected cell in TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a customTableViewCell in a tableView. I am highlighting the cell when selected using,

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;`

But, the tableView appears like the following image.

[image]

It hides the labels and text in the customCell. I just want to highlight the cell simply without hiding the background image and labels. I do not know where I am making the mistake, whether in  code or IB. .

Comment: Did you customize your Tableview?

Comment: How did you add your subviews to the cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey i think you need to add labels and texts in the customCell to **cell.contentview**. For reference go to Apple developer document.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

Answer (score 4):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.Your_imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your_image_Name.png"];
```

this will work fine

Comment: for this you need to use CustomTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

```
[_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
```

put this in to view Will Appear and its works for me ,

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

also put this to .h file too

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView *viewSelected = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    viewSelected.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_highlighted.PNG"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = viewSelected;
```